# MongoDB: Server has startup warnings ''Access control is not enabled for the database''

Tags: mongodb

I firstly installed MongoDB 3.4.1 today. But when I start it and use MongoDB shell, it gave me these warnings below:

```
C:\Users\hs>"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\mongo.exe
MongoDB shell version v3.4.1
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.4.1
Server has startup warnings:
2017-01-12T21:19:46.941+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2017-01-12T21:19:46.942+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2017-01-12T21:19:46.942+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2017-01-12T21:19:46.942+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
```

my computer is Microsoft Windows [`version 10.0.14393`].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB: Server has startup warnings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36660117/mongodb-server-has-startup-warnings)

Comment: This is almost a perfect duplicate of another question.  Did you happen to already have asked this last year under a different username?  The only thing that is different is the username and version of Windows.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36660117/mongodb-server-has-startup-warnings

Comment: @JosephFerris, Yes, this is duplication for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36660117/mongodb-server-has-startup-warnings and that question has closed because of this duplication.

Answer (score 158):

Mongodb v3.4

You need to do the following to create a secure database:

Make sure the user starting the process has permissions and that the directories exist (`/data/db` in this case).

1) Start MongoDB without access control.

```
mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db
```

2) Connect to the instance.

```
mongo --port 27017
```

3) Create the user administrator *(in the admin authentication database)*.

```
use admin
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "myUserAdmin",
    pwd: "abc123",
    roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
  }
)
```

4) Re-start the MongoDB instance with access control.

```
mongod --auth --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db
```

5) Connect and authenticate as the user administrator.

```
mongo --port 27017 -u "myUserAdmin" -p "abc123" --authenticationDatabase "admin"
```

6) Create additional users as needed for your deployment *(e.g. in the test authentication database)*.

```
use test
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "myTester",
    pwd: "xyz123",
    roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "test" },
             { role: "read", db: "reporting" } ]
  }
)
```

7) Connect and authenticate as myTester.

```
mongo --port 27017 -u "myTester" -p "xyz123" --authenticationDatabase "test"
```

I basically just explained the short version of the official docs here: https://docs.mongodb.com/master/tutorial/enable-authentication/

Comment: I do like you said but just one problem is that this --auth have to pass every time or for one time. if everytime then how to give with service because in a server I want to like this sudo service MongoDB start?

Comment: @sureshpareek You can configure this in the mongodb.conf file if you do not want to pass it everytime, more info here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#security-options

Comment: @sureshpareek No problem man! Check here if you wanna know more about it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42929869/1137669 I explain in in a little more detail.

Comment: I fail in first step .I was version v3.6.5 .The same warning and it shutdown

Comment: Seriously guys... Why you don't say to enable the `security.authorization` in `mongod.conf` ??????

Comment: @John because you don't need to when you have the following flag set like in the post: `mongod --auth`

Answer (score 11):

All you need to do is to:

1. Edit your config, e.g. `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin\mongodb.cfg`
2. Turn the `security: authorization:` to `enabled`, as illustrated; note that this sub-entry may be missing completely. Just add it then.
3. Restart your `MongoDB Server` service from the Windows **Services** control panel.

[image]

Obviously, if, following this, set up a read/readWrite role-based policy, that will make much more sense.

Ref: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-scram-client-authentication/

I've just tested this using phpunit, works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

you can create an admin user or another [role](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/built-in-roles/).
run it on mongo shell.

```
db.createUser({user: "username", pwd: "password", roles: ["dbAdmin"]})
```

if you get SCRAM-SHA-256error you can set the SHA-1 mechanism.

```
db.createUser({user: "username", pwd: "password", roles: ["dbAdmin"], mechanisms: ["SCRAM-SHA-1"]})
```

Answer (score -13):

You need to delete your old db folder and recreate new one. It will resolve your issue.