# Add simple read write user in mongo 3.4.1

Tags: mongodb

I can't believe that there is no simple example for this. I keep reading different versions everywhere.

```
mongo --port 27017 -u "admin" -p "mypass" --authenticationDatabase "mydb"
use mydb
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "normal",
    pwd: "anotherpass",
    roles: [ { role: "readWriteAnyDatabase", db: "mydb" } ]
  }
)
```

I get:

```
Error: couldn't add user: No role named readWriteAnyDatabase
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41615574/mongodb-server-has-startup-warnings-access-control-is-not-enabled-for-the-dat

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42929869/1137669

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the website:

> Changed in version 3.4: Prior to 3.4, readWriteAnyDatabase includes
>   local and config databases. To provide readWrite privileges on the
>   local database, create a user in the admin database with readWrite
>   role in the local database.

If you want the desired output, I believe you just have to go to the admin database `use admin` and create an user with the following command:

```
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "normal",
    pwd: "anotherpass",
    roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "mydb" } ]
  }
)
```