# In MongoDB, can I add a regular user that can read any non-admin DB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-security

I have MongoDB set up on my laptop for a MEAN Stack university class I'm taking this semester, but of course I don't know what databases I'll be creating for the class, nor how many.

I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42355886/add-simple-read-write-user-in-mongo-3-4-1) about adding users to MongoDB, and I have a regular user for myself for non-admin stuff. From what I can see in the answer to that question, and from [this page of the Mongo documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/create-users/), it is not possible to create a user that can read a database that is to be created in the future. Is this indeed the case, or is there some hard-to-find way around it?

Answer (score 0):

The permissions do not need to reference existing databases. For a role that has read access to most databases, see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#mongodb-authrole-readAnyDatabase.

You may be confused with the concept of auth source/authentication database in MongoDB. Users may be defined in the `admin` database which bypasses the issue of them referencing databases that don't exist yet.

Comment: If I need to create databases for class, which I assume I will, shouldn't I instead be using `readWriteAnyDatabase`? Or is that a bad idea?

Indeed, I don't really know what I'm doing. I'm not as familiar with Mongo as MySQL (even still not that familiar), so I might not be finding the right resources.

Comment: For testing purposes on a development computer you do not need authentication at all. If your class requires specific permissions and users, do whatever the requirements are.