# this is the warning , how to solve this?

Tags: mongodb

Server has startup warnings:

```
2020-04-05T03:04:33.339+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2020-04-05T03:04:33.339+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2020-04-05T03:04:33.339+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2020-04-05T03:04:33.340+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB: Server has startup warnings ''Access control is not enabled for the database''](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41615574/mongodb-server-has-startup-warnings-access-control-is-not-enabled-for-the-dat)

Answer (score 1):

How to solve:

[Enable access control](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/)