# Mongo : db.auth() fails on windows

Tags: mongodb, docker

I'm trying to run a mongo instance on a windows container.

I have found this answer regarding authentication but I does not work for me
[MongoDB: Server has startup warnings ''Access control is not enabled for the database''](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41615574/mongodb-server-has-startup-warnings-access-control-is-not-enabled-for-the-dat)

I have a cfg file which I'm using to start mongo, my image is based on an existing mongo docker image on top of which I'm just copying my config file amd I'm trying to instruct mongo to use it. I actually don't know if it really does this, but as far as I know the base image CMD is overriden with my new CMD.

This is the dockerfile

```
FROM mongo:windowsservercore-1809

WORKDIR c:\
COPY .\mongod.Win.cfg .

CMD ["mongod", "--auth", "-f", "mongod.Win.cfg"]
```

And this is my mongod.win.cfg

```
storage:
  dbPath: C:\data\db
  journal:
    enabled: true
    
security:
  authorization: enabled
```

And I'm building the image in a docker-compose

```
invoice_db:
    build:
      context: ./Invoice.Db
      dockerfile: ./mongo.win.Dockerfile
    image: mongo:v1
    container_name: invoice-db
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: "admin"
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: "pass"
    volumes:
      - invoice-data-volume:c:\data\db
    restart: unless-stopped

volumes:
  invoice-data-volume:
    name: invoice-data
```

When I ssh in the container and try to login as admin with the password pass I get this

```
PS C:\> mongo
MongoDB shell version v5.0.9
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("17467fb1-ecf9-426c-9041-0f15c3a47d30") }
MongoDB server version: 5.0.9
================
Warning: the "mongo" shell has been superseded by "mongosh",
which delivers improved usability and compatibility.The "mongo" shell has been deprecated and will be removed in
an upcoming release.
For installation instructions, see
https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/install/
================
Welcome to the MongoDB shell.
For interactive help, type "help".
For more comprehensive documentation, see
        https://docs.mongodb.com/
Questions? Try the MongoDB Developer Community Forums
        https://community.mongodb.com
> use admin
switched to db admin
> db.auth("admin", "pass")
Error: Authentication failed.
0
> db.auth("admin", passwordPrompt())
Enter password:
Error: Authentication failed.
0
>
```

The logs from the running container.

{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-18T23:38:10.420+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":20436,   "ctx":"conn1","msg":"Checking authorization failed","attr":{"error":{"code":13,"codeName":"Unauthorized","errmsg":"not authorized on admin to execute command { getCmdLineOpts: 1.0, lsid: { id: UUID("17467fb1-ecf9-426c-9041-0f15c3a47d30") }, $db: "admin" }"}}}

{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-18T23:38:18.120+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":20436,   "ctx":"conn1","msg":"Checking authorization failed","attr":{"error":{"code":13,"codeName":"Unauthorized","errmsg":"not authorized on admin to execute command { listCollections: 1.0, filter: {}, nameOnly: true, authorizedCollections: true, maxTimeMS: 1000.0, lsid: { id: UUID("17467fb1-ecf9-426c-9041-0f15c3a47d30") }, $db: "admin" }"}}}

{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-18T23:38:21.712+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":20251,   "ctx":"conn1","msg":"Supported SASL mechanisms requested for unknown user","attr":{"user":{"user":"admin","db":"admin"}}}

{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-18T23:38:21.713+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":20249,   "ctx":"conn1","msg":"Authentication failed","attr":{"mechanism":"SCRAM-SHA-1","speculative":false,"principalName":"admin","authenticationDatabase":"admin","remote":"127.0.0.1:49160","extraInfo":{},"error":"UserNotFound: Could not find user "admin" for db "admin""}}

{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-18T23:38:25.438+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":20436,   "ctx":"conn1","msg":"Checking authorization failed","attr":{"error":{"code":13,"codeName":"Unauthorized","errmsg":"not authorized on admin to execute command { listCollections: 1.0, filter: {}, nameOnly: true, authorizedCollections: true, maxTimeMS: 1000.0, lsid: { id: UUID("17467fb1-ecf9-426c-9041-0f15c3a47d30") }, $db: "admin" }"}}}

{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-18T23:38:32.311+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":20251,   "ctx":"conn1","msg":"Supported SASL mechanisms requested for unknown user","attr":{"user":{"user":"admin","db":"admin"}}}

{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-18T23:38:32.312+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":20249,   "ctx":"conn1","msg":"Authentication failed","attr":{"mechanism":"SCRAM-SHA-1","speculative":false,"principalName":"admin","authenticationDatabase":"admin","remote":"127.0.0.1:49160","extraInfo":{},"error":"UserNotFound: Could not find user "admin" for db "admin""}}

{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-18T23:38:37.028+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"Checkpointer","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1658176717:28384][1272:140723313332832], WT_SESSION.checkpoint: [WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS] saving checkpoint snapshot min: 34, snapshot max: 34 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (0, 0) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (0, 0) base write gen: 1"}}

{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-18T23:39:37.051+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"Checkpointer","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1658176777:50893][1272:140723313332832], WT_SESSION.checkpoint: [WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS] saving checkpoint snapshot min: 37, snapshot max: 37 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (0, 0) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (0, 0) base write gen: 1"}}

{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-18T23:40:37.067+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"Checkpointer","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1658176837:67089][1272:140723313332832], WT_SESSION.checkpoint: [WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS] saving checkpoint snapshot min: 39, snapshot max: 39 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (0, 0) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (0, 0) base write gen: 1"}}

Can someone help me figure out this ?

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
db.auth({user:"admin", pwd:"pass", mechanism:"SCRAM"})
```